# OnClick not working with my element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create an anchor tag and then a `click` event handler, but the event is not triggering. I think the jQuery syntax is incorrect?

```js
var b = '<a class="dz-remove removeAttachment">Remove</a>';
var someOtherElement = $(dropZoneElement).find(".dz-file-preview")[0];
$(someOtherElement).append(b);
$(b).on('click', function() {
  dropone.removeAllFiles();
})
```

Comment: `b` is just a string, you need to select the appended dom element before adding event listeners to it.

Comment: I just want to make sure I'm selecting the correct one, because this snippet is in a loop so multiple are added to my page

Comment: With `b` you aren't referencing an existing element in the DOM. You would need to select the element you just appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind an event to a string.

You should bind it to the DOM elements. As you are adding the DOM element after loading the entire document, using 'delegate' helps you.

This should work:

```
var b = '<a class="dz-remove removeAttachment">Remove</a>';
$(someOtherElement).append(b);
$(someOtherElement).delegate('.removeAttachment', 'click', function() {
  dropone.removeAllFiles();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you actually create two independent anchor elements: here `$(someOtherElement).append(b)` and here `$(b).`.

Use code below. I presume you have `dropone` and `dropZoneElement` defined somewhere above this snippet.

```
var $b = $('<a class="dz-remove removeAttachment">Remove</a>');
$b.click( function() { dropone.removeAllFiles(); });
$(dropZoneElement).find(".dz-file-preview:first").append($b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Var b is still a string not a Dom element,  you have to select the inserted element for example by class,  then assign click event to it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var b = '<a class="dz-remove removeAttachment">Remove</a>';
var someOtherElement = $(dropZoneElement).find(".dz-file-preview")[0];
$(someOtherElement).append(b);
$(someOtherElement).find('a').on('click', function() {
  dropone.removeAllFiles();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that your `var b` is a string. What you need to do is to create a dom element and add the event listener to that element.

Change `var b` to

```
var b = $.parseHTML('<a class="dz-remove removeAttachment">Remove</a>'); // $.parseHTML is a jQuery method to create HTML from a string
```

which creates a HTML element and when you add on click event to `var b` it will work properly.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5nx6u18n/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve easily with replace

```
$(b).on('click', function() {
  dropone.removeAllFiles();
});
```

with

```
$('.dz-remove').on('click', function() {
  // your code....
});
```

and you can see your all code is working well :)

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a lot of extra work for yourself in generating the elements like that. In addition, there are a few problems with the way that that code is executing. First, you're creating two independent anchor tags, here `.append(b);` and here `$(b)`. Secondly, you're attaching your event handler to the second anchor tag that you create but you're not inserting that tag into the DOM.

Thankfully, we can fix this. In referencing the jQuery Docs, you'll see that the vast majority of functions return `jQuery`. This is great because it allows us to chain together commands and reduce the complexity of the code. Try the following:

```
$('<a />', { "class": "dz-remove removeAttachment", text: "Remove" })
    .appendTo($(dropZoneElement).find(".dz-file-preview"))
    .on('click', function () {
        dropone.removeAllFiles();
    });
```

**DEMO:**

```js
// Document Ready
$(function () {
    $('<a />', { "class": "dz-remove removeAttachment", text: "Remove" })
        .appendTo($('#dropzoneElement').find(".dz-file-preview"))
        .on('click', function () {
            alert("I'm chained!");
        });
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: red;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
a:hover {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropzoneElement">
  <div class="dz-file-preview"></div>
</div>
```